# ngram a database file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, n-gram

I am trying to ngram my database file. It works when I ngram a parsed string, but I do not know how to do the same for my database file. 
I have the following code so far:

(hopefully I am in the right track)

```
require 'ngram'
require 'sqlite3'

ngram = NGram.new({
  :size => 2,
  :word_separator => " ",
  :padchar => "_"
})

p ngram.parse('something')
# => ["__", "_t", "te", "es", "st", "t_", "__"]
p ngram.parse('test phrase')

db = SQLite3::Database.new("sample.db") #opens db
#ngram sample.db
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the [github code of ngram gem's](https://github.com/tkellen/ruby-ngram/blob/f8aa9bdd40d44d130c6511301b3498037ac1e031/lib/ngram.rb#L11-L18) `parse` method:

```
def parse(phrase)
    words = phrase.split(@separator)
    if words.length == 1
        process(phrase)
    else
        words.map { |w| process(w) }
    end
end
```

So, it's expecting a string object so that it can call [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) on it. That's why it works with your first example where you pass a string as an argument to the `ngram.parse` method.

I am not exactly sure what you want to accomplish here, but as long as you pass a string to the `ngram.parse` method, it would work. Or, at least, pass an argument that responds to the `split` method.